# datatype change in partitioned tables

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes, alter-table, database-partitioning, mysql-5.7

We are using MySQL 5.7.17

We have two big tables in production of almost the same size, one is a partitioned table and another is not partitioned. We are trying to change the datatype of a field from varchar(45) to varchar(50).

We first tried in the non-partitioned table and it completed within a second, but when we tried the same in the partitioned table, it is taking more time, and thus we canceled it.

What will be the reason for taking more time in a partitioned table, maybe a table rebuild is happening in this case, but I couldn't find a good document explaining this.

Please share your knowledge regarding this so that we can understand what is really happening underneath it.

Comment: *What will be the reason for taking more time in a partitioned table* Your altering operation is online for solid table but COPY is used for partitioned table. Try to specify INPLACE method explicitly - and you'd see that it canot be applied to the partitioned table. PS. Alter to varchar(255) or at least 192. For the future... this won't increase needed storage size.

Answer (score 0):

`pt-online-schema-change` may provide a way to perform the task with minimal impact, though still not fast.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the main query for which you decided to `PARTITION` the table.  I may try to argue that you should get rid of partitioning.